# Flask Session not persistant in blueprint

Tags: python, session, flask

I am using a blueprint to build a web application. I am having issue with sessions not being persistent. I can start the session but when I click a link the session is lost. What am I doing incorrectly? I am not using a database to login I am just hard coding. 
When I submit I do
    session['username'] = me. 
On the page that I redirect to after the login it works. But when I click a link from that page, the session is lost. The
    session['username'] 
is gone. I do have my secret key set as well. It is hard coded in my config file.
In my admin folder I have a routes file with my login.  The login works, but when I click a link to go to a different page the username is lost.

```
C:.
└───blueprintsite
├───admin
│   ├───templates
│   │   └───admin
│   └───__pycache__
├───reports
│   └───__pycache__
├───users
│   ├───templates
│   │   └───site
│   └───__pycache__
├───static
│   ├───css
│   ├───fonts
│   ├───images
│   │   ├───media
│   │   ├───people
│   │   └───preview
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello you can start using [Flask-Login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to handle your user authentication and session management, good things is with flask-login you wont have to worry about session management across your blueprints as it will automatically do that for you. I have been using it for my Blueprint applications for years now and it works perfectly for me.

Give it a read and I hope it helps you

Comment: I was using the incorrect url. I was using 127 but the cookie was signed localhost. Thanks for the advice. Is there a sort of complete build an app using blueprints guide anywher?

Comment: you can check the official site or follow this simple guide on Digital Ocean https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-structure-large-flask-applications

Answer (score 2):

This issue may occur when the `SESSION_COOKIE_PATH` (or `APPLICATION_ROOT`) [configuration values](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/config/) for your Flask app do not include the path that the Blueprint is set up to route for.

For example, if the `APPLICATION_ROOT` of your app is set up to be `/pages`, but your Blueprint is prefixed for `/admin`, the session cookie of the former won't be valid for the latter. Setting `SESSION_COOKIE_PATH` explicitly to `/` should do the trick, in this case.

Comment: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/ in this current version it says  "SESSION_COOKIE_PATH
   The path that the session cookie will be valid for. If not set, the cookie will be valid underneath APPLICATION_ROOT or / if that is not set."
what i want to ask is is each blueprint count a new application which gives APPLICATION_ROOT its own value. Sorry I am new with flask